# YouTube Data API: default quota allocation of 10,000 - is it per authed user or per app?

Tags: api, automation, youtube, zapier, quota

Similarly to Zapier, Make would like to integrate Youtube and provide the users possibility to automate their tasks. As the Youtube Data API has a default quota of 10000 units per day, is the quota per authed user or per app?

It seems that the whole app is counted, which would not be possible for this funcionality.

Answer (score 0):

"Projects that enable the YouTube Data API have a default quota allocation of 10,000 units per day"

Source: [Youtube Data API Overview](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#:%7E:text=Quota%20usage,-The%20YouTube%20Data&text=You%20can%20find%20the%20quota,majority%20of%20our%20API%20users.)

This means it is based on the project/app, not the user.

However, you can always request a higher quota here: [Youtube API Extension Form](https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form)